# Buying monitoring headphones

Tags: headphones

i want to buy a akg 240 mk2 headphone. But when i compare the prices, amazon sold them 78 $ , when akg own website sell them 149 $.how is that possible? Are they fake?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about consumer AV purchasing, not music.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's current UK pricing, from online retailers and direct from AKG.  It seems AKG are offering a discount that matches the 'street price'.  Maybe there's a 'new, improved'  model about to be released?   It seems likely you're being offered genuine product.

[image]